# How to get state from parent in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a TabNavigator like this :

```
        <TabNavigator>

            <TabNavigator.Item
                selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'home'}
                title="Home"
                renderIcon={() => <Image source={icon1}/>}
                renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image source={require('./img/slider-left.png')}/>}
                onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'home' })}
                >
                <MainNav selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}
                    getSelectedTab = {() => this.state.selectedTab}/>

            </TabNavigator.Item>
            <TabNavigator.Item
                selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'profile'}
                title="Profile"
                renderIcon={() => <Image source={icon1}/>}
                renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image source={icon1}/>} 
                onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'profile' })}
                >
                <TopicNav selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab} /*this does not work*//>
            </TabNavigator.Item>

        </TabNavigator>
```

and In **MainNav** and **TopicNav** （in seperated files） they both have a **Navigator** stack, and **BackAndroid** to process physical back events, where two **BackAndroid** can get back event at the same time, like this:

```
BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
    if (_navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length === 1  ) {
        return false;
    } 
    _navigator.pop();
    return true;
});
```

I need to get to know the current **shown** TAB, and only respond to the **shown** **one**. How can I get the parent state **selectedTab** when it changes? Thanks.

Comment: The approach you are taking seams correct to me. Pass in this.state.selectedTab as prop. Whats the issue?

Comment: @dvinemultimedia  In TopicNavTab , It don't know the selectedTab changes when I click MainVav Tab.

Comment: But as soon as you change a tab the this.sate.selectedTab of the parent changes. This triggers a re-render of all the tab with the new selectedTab prop. So in the components via this.props.selectedTab should always reflect the currently selected tab.

Comment: If Parent have four childern ABCD, and First set A to be selected ,and then set B, and A don't know the B is selected. I fixed this by pass down a getter function as props to all childern and they can get the state when they want. Thanks dvine.